# elinks or w3m command line browser - How to use vpn

Tags: command-line, w3m, elinks

I am using elinks and w3m for command line browsing and it works great. How do I use vpn or browse without using my ip address using elinks or w3m?

Answer (score 0):

Install tor and torscks
Maybe need run tor command, then in another terminal session run:

```bash
torsocks -i w3m http://ifconfig.me/ip
torsocks -i elinks http://ifconfig.me/ip
```